# How to determine at which number exponential series coincide?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a relatively simple question that I came across when solving a Limits problem, but I can't find a simple mathematical way to solve it.

Consider two exponential series, of powers of two distinct integers $A$ and $B$. So one series is $$\{A^{1},A^{2},A^{3},...,A^{x}\}$$
and the other is $$\{B^{1},B^{2},B^{3},...,B^{y}\}$$

**How can I find at which values of $x$ and $y$, $A^{x} = B^{y}$?**

Comment: Consider the prime factorization of each.

Comment: @JMoravitz Prime factors of $A$ and $B$ or $A^{x}$ and $B^{y}$? I don't see how that could help. What if $A$ and $B$ are prime?

Comment: Prime factors of $A$ and $B$.  You should be able to convince yourself that $A^x = B^y$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ are both perfect powers of some $C$, i.e. $C^a=A$ and $C^b=B$., and when $A^{bk} = B^{ak}$ for any integer $k$. where here $x=bk$ and $y=ak$.

Comment: For example, with $A=4$ and $B=8$, you have $4,16,64,256,1024,4096,\dots$ and you have $8,64, 512,4096,\dots$.  Compare this to when, say $A=2$ and $B=3$.  $2,4,8,16,32,\dots$ is always even, and $3,9,27,81,243,\dots$ is never even.  Generalize to the case of arbitrary prime decompositions.